# Riak (Java Client) suddenly stopped creating secondary indexes

Tags: java, scala, jackson, riak

Note I am using the Java client in Scala. `case class` annotations are slightly different. I have the following POJO:

```
case class User(
  @(JsonProperty@field)("guid")
  @(RiakKey@field)
  val guid: String,

  @(JsonProperty@field)("email")
  @(JsonSerialize@field)(using=classOf[util.serialization.StringToUrlSerializer])
  @(JsonDeserialize@field)(using=classOf[util.serialization.StringToUrlDeserializer])
  @(RiakIndex@field)(name = "email")
  val email: String,

  @(JsonProperty@field)("passwordHash")
  val passwordHash: String
)
```

Suddenly, Riak stopped storing a secondary index for my `User`. We can still create secondary indexes manually if we use the raw HTTP API via a REST client but in the code I am at a loss to explain why it is failing.

Here is how we store Riak Objects:

```
/**
   * Riak database operations
   */
  val bucketName = "accounts-user"
  val bucket = DB.client.createBucket(bucketName).enableForSearch().execute()
  val converter = {
    val c = new JSONConverter[User](classOf[User], bucketName)
    c.getObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    c
  }

  def store(o: User) = bucket.store(o).withConverter(converter).withRetrier(DB.retrier).execute()
```

The Jackson imports we're using are as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation._

import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala._
```

The objects are being stored successfully and errors are not being thrown. What might be the cause to the issue? Does the `DefaultScalaModule` for Jackson possibly interfere with annotations? FYI I did try removing the custom converter but it did not solve the issue (did not remove any Scala Module imports, however). Thanks.

### Edit

Possibly related: recently we started proxying Riak via NGINX. Do I need to do both HTTP and TCP `proxy_pass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I suspected, proxying using NGINX was the culprit. Although I was using the HTTP client to access buckets, the Riak Java Client was actually using a lower-level (probably PBC) protocol to create the secondary indexes. Not sure why it was failing silently (could be due to design) but as soon as I switched NGINX from HTTP to TCP forwarding the issue immediately was resolved.